# Sesame caching common queries

Tags: caching, sesame

I use Sesame in a JSP web based application and  I would like to know if there is any way to cache some queries that are used consistently.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about what exactly you're trying to achieve? What's your precise setup and what exactly do you need cached?

Comment: i have some sparql queries like "select ?att ?value where {placeid ?att ?value}".  I do this query for 30 places and i want to "cache" them if they have been used

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you want to "cache" is the query *result* for a given query with specific value. You can very easily build such a cache yourself. Just create a class for the general query that internally keeps a reference to a HashMap that maps from a value key (e.g. the placeid for your example query) to a query result:

```java
HashMap<URI, TupleQueryResult> cache = new HashMap<>();
```

Then all you do is check, for a given place id, if it is present in the cache. If it is not, you execute the query, get the result back and materialize it as a [`MutableTupleQueryResult`](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/query/impl/MutableTupleQueryResult.html) which you can then put in that cache:

```java
if (!cache.contains(placeId)) {
       // reuse the prepared query with the specific binding for which we want a result
       preparedQuery.setBinding("placeid", placeId);

       // execute the query and add the result to a result object we can reuse multiple times
       TupleQueryResult result = new MutableTupleQueryResult(preparedQuery.evaluate());

       // put the result in the cache.
       cache.put(placeId, result);
}
return cache.get(placeId);
```

If you want something a bit more sophisticated (e.g. something that throws out cached items after a certain time, or sets a size limit on your cache), I would have a look at using something like a [Guava Cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) instead of a simple `HashMap`, but the basic setup would remain the same.